# Inheritance in Laravel framework

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent, models

Is possibile to use inheritance in laravel model? I explain:

is possible to exend a model, which extends eloquent class?

```
class A extends Eloquent
{
}

class B extends A
{
}
```

A e B are also 2 different tables and B has A_id as foreignkey and other fields.
How could be the constructor of class B?
is it a ragionable solution or better use hasOne relationship?

no every A object are also B object. Es. user and teacher

Thank you

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I’m having difficulty understanding your supplementary details, but in answer to the actual question: yes, it is possible to extend Eloquent models.

```
<?php
class User extends \Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'users';

}

class Student extends User {

    protected $table = 'students';

}
```

Be warned though, that any methods (such as relations, scopes etc) **will** propagate to the extending class. If this is not desired, then create a base class that has the minimum of what you need, and then sub-class it with your specific types, i.e. `Student`, `Administrator` etc.

Another approach is to use interfaces. So if you *know* models need the same attributes but will say, have different relations; then you can create an interface to add those constraints:

```
<?php
interface UserInterface {

    public function getName();

}

class User extends \Eloquent implements UserInterface {

    protected $table = 'users';

    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

}

class Student extends \Eloquent implements UserInterface {

    protected $table = 'students';

    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function courses()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Course');
    }

    public function grades()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Grade');
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you. can you explain me the first solution in case i don't want to propagate relations and other? you told me about baseclass. but the baseclass is user class, no? so what is the difference? thank you

Comment: You would have a base `User` class that has the bare bones, and then you would define classes for more specific types of users, that has the relations and whatnot you wanted.

Comment: thanks but how i can define the constructor of subclass if it is in another table? the only relation between 2 classes is a foreing key like user_id in sublcass table

Comment: You don’t need to declare the constructor. You would call the models the same as you do normally, i.e. `$students = Student::get()`.

Comment: Sure. The problem is when the superclass instance call a method of the subclass which has a relation with another table and it uses the wrong foreignkey (the superclass one) in the query. See the example below in my answer.Thank you for patience.

Comment: That’s why you would create a base class that contains only the **bare minimum** of what’s needed, and then define relations and whatnot in sub-classes.

Answer (score 0):

I resolve with

```
class A extends Eloquent 
{
   protected $table  = 'a';
}

class B extends A
{
   protected $table  = 'b';
   protected $primaryKey = 'a_id';
}
```

but in the main function:

`$f = B::find(1);`
`$f->method();`

where the method() is a method of A class,
the system gives to me an mysql error:

`` select * from `C` where `C`.`B_id` = 1 ``


the error is `B_id`. It should be `A_id` cause the method should be applied from subobject of the class, not from the class